# how to add onClick function to array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, onclick

I am trying to add onClick function to this array. So when i click on "How will i get cashback?",[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE3tq.png)

it must display the items(Page Page One,Two) [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBeZ0.png) and when i click on "Page Page One", it must display "Subcontent"

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8dnkvv?file=src%2FApp.js)

```
export default class Chat extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    title: "How will i get cashback?",
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            title: "Page Page One",
                            items: [
                                     {
                                        id: 1,
                                        title: 'SubContent'
                                      }
                                   ],
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            title: "Two",
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: "Reschedule delivery",
                    items: [],
                },
            ], 
        };
    }
    render() {
        const { message } = this.state;
        return (
                <div>
                        <p className={styles.titleText}>AAAAAA</p>
                        <div className={styles.line} />
                        {message.map((m) => (
                            <div>
                                <div
                                    className={styles.button}
                                >
                                    {m.title}
                                    <i
                                        className={`fa fa-chevron-right`}
                                        aria-hidden="true"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className={styles.line} />
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this change to your code.

Basically what you are telling your program is "If I have `items`, then set the state to be these items, else do nothing"

```
<div className={`button`} onClick={() => m.items ? this.setState({ message: m.items }) : null}>
  {m.title}
  <i className={`fa fa-chevron-right`} aria-hidden="true" />
</div>
```